# Class member not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c

I want to program a deterministic finite automata and require two classes. State and transition, but I want to include two transition type objects in the class but I brand state that does not recognize one transition.

Trans.h:

```
 #ifndef TRANS_H
 #define TRANS_H
 using namespace std;
 #include <string>
 class Trans
 {
     private:
         int direccion;
         string simbolo;

     public:
         Trans();
         Trans(int dir, string sim);
         void setsm(string sm);
         void setdir(int dir);
         int getdir();
         string getsm();
         virtual ~Trans();
 };
 #endif // TRANS_H
```

Trans.c:

```
 #include "Trans.h"

 #include <string.h>
 Trans::Trans(int dir,string sim)
 {
     direccion=dir;
     simbolo=sim;
 }

 Trans::~Trans()
 {
     //dtor
 }
 void Trans::setsm(string sm){
     simbolo=sm;
 }
 void Trans::setdir(int dir){
     direccion=dir;
 }
 int Trans::getdir(){
     return direccion;
 }
 string Trans::getsm(){
     return simbolo;
 }
```

Estado.h:

```
 #ifndef ESTADO_H
 #define ESTADO_H
 using namespace std;
 #include <string>
 #include "Trans.h"

 class Estado
 {
     private:
         int ident;
         bool estInit;
          bool estEnd;
          Trans transicion1;
          Trans transicion2;

     public: 
         Estado();
         ~Estado();
         Estado(int ident,bool inits,bool ends);
         void setIdent(int id);
         void setInitS(bool inits);
    void setEndS(bool ends);
    void setTrans1(Trans transis);
    void setTrans2(Trans transis);
         int getIdent();
    bool getInitS();
    bool getEndS();
    Trans getTrans1();
    Trans getTrans2();                 
 };

 #endif // TRANS_H
```

Estado.c

```
     #include "Estado.h"
     #include "Trans.h"

     using namespace std;

     Estado::Estado(int ident,bool inits,bool ends)
     {
         this->ident=ident;
         this->estInit=inits;
         this->estEnd=ends;
     }
     Estado::Estado()
     {
         estInit=false;
         estEnd=false;
     }
     Estado::~Estado(){

}
void Estado::setIdent(int id){
    ident=id;
}
void Estado::setInitS(bool inits){
    estInit=inits;
}
void Estado::setEndS(bool ends){
    estEnd=ends;
}
void setTrans1(Trans transis){
transicion1=new Trans();
}
void setTrans2(Trans transis){
    transicion2=transis;
}
int Estado::getIdent(){
    return ident;
}
bool Estado::getInitS(){
    return estInit;
}
bool Estado::getEndS(){
    return estEnd;
}
Trans getTrans1(){
    return transicion1;
}
Trans getTrans2(){
    return transicion2;
}
```

Error:

```
 g++ -c     -c -o Estado.o Estado.c 
 Estado.c: In function ‘void setTrans1(Trans)’: 
 Estado.c:30: error: ‘transicion1’ was not declared in this scope 
 Estado.c: In function ‘void setTrans2(Trans)’: 
 Estado.c:33: error: ‘transicion2’ was not declared in this scope 
 Estado.c: In function ‘Trans getTrans1()’: 
 Estado.c:45: error: ‘transicion1’ was not declared in this scope 
 Estado.c: In function ‘Trans getTrans2()’: 
 Estado.c:48: error: ‘transicion2’ was not declared in this scope 
 make: *** [Estado.o] Error
```

Comment: Why are you writing c++ code in `.c` files?

Comment: Is this for a class in school? Cause if not, classes are a really tedious way to implement state machines. In fact, state machines are kindof the poster child for when to not use classes (although the godawful Visitor pattern that students are taught to use when parsing is a close second :-)

Comment: I guess userX cannot be bothered to narrow the problem down. So why should I go through that mass of code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
void setTrans1(Trans transis)
```

is not the same as

```
void Estado::setTrans1(Trans transis)
```

The first declares a free function (as opposed to a member), so class members aren't directly accessible inside.